# .ajax call not sending data

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code which worked yesterday but has mysteriously stopped working today:

```
$.ajax({
  url:        "folder_setup.php?",    
  type:       "POST",
  dataType:   'text',
  contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
  processData:false,
  data:       postString('#artistfield','#folderfield','#picturefield','#biogfield'),        
  cache:      false,
  success:    function (data) { 
    // get foldername from success result and display
  } // end success function
}); // end ajax
```

I know that the 'postString' function works as I get it to echo it's output to the console, it renders this string:

```
artist=Pablo Picasso&folder=pablo_picasso&picture=Pablo1.jpg&biography=Great Spanish painter.&
```

Like I say, this worked yesterday and the string was sent. I've tried all manner of things - fiddling with the .ajax options, assigning the postString output to a string first, making the request a GET, etc.. Can't seem to work it out. I added the contentType line today but it makes no difference if it's there or not.I know my php works as I've tested it independently.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you describe in what manner it has stopped working? Have you verified that this line of code is being reached? Can you see on the server logs if the request is being made? Can you use Firebug or Developer Tools to see what the response from the server is? Is your success function simply not getting called?

Comment: The request is being made but the string's not going with it.

Comment: I'm very new to the game, as you can surely tell. I'm using an Apache local host on a Mac - do you know where the server log files would be please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity...  Are you using Firefox with Firebug?  If not, then open the page with Firebug to see what is going on.  Firebug has solved my problem (just like this one) many times.

Comment: Respectfully, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am indeed using Firebug and it's not enlightening me as to my problem so I'm still stuck. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @RichJohnstone - in the Console tab does it show the call to folder_setup.php? (i.e. GET:http://...)  That is usually an indicator for me if the call is even being made.  If it is not, maybe you aren't making the call to the function properly or there is an error before your .ajax call...

Comment: The call is being made but the string's not being sent with it.

Comment: What string?  the results from postString?

Comment: @Rich - Maybe your issues is that your string of parameters is not the correct syntax.  maybe build your url string above the call to make sure the syntax is correct and then just pass that string for your URL:

Comment: @Rich - I'm glad I could help you out.